# Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action..?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting the DoubleRenderError and I cannot figure out why! Basically, I have an action that calls another action that checks a user inputted query for errors, and if theres an error, its stops and displays the error. But when i type in a query with an error, that when i get the double render! Any suggstions?

Heres the error checker action:

```
def if_user_formulated_request_properly
    unless request.post?
      flash[:error] = "This page can only be accessed through the search page. (POST request only)"
 redirect_to(:action => "index") and return
    end

    if params[:query].blank?
      flash[:error] = "Search criteria can not be blank"
redirect_to(:action => "index") and  return
    end

    if !(params[:query] =~ /-/)
      flash[:error] = "( Format of search criteria is wrong.<br /> Should be [IXLSpecClass value][year]-[Message ID] for exam
ple GP07-8)"
redirect_to(:action => "index") and  return
    end

    if !(QueryParser.expression.match(params[:query]))
      flash[:error] = %( Format of search criteria is wrong.<br />Should be [IXLSpecClass value][year]-[Message ID] for examp
le GP07-8)
redirect_to(:action => "index") and return
  end
 yield
```

And just in case you need the action calling this action..

```
 def show
        if_user_formulated_request_properly do
        @statuses = IXLStatus.find(:all)
        @input_messages = InputMessage.search_by(params[:query].stri
p) unless params[:query].blank?
        @query = params[:query]
        end
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html #default rendering
        end
        end
  end
```

**UPDATE**

Also forgot to mention, this originally was a rails 2 app and was working, this error started when i upgraded to rails 3 (i believe), so maybe rails 3 does something different with `and return`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're only returning from the `if_user_formulated_request_properly` method, which means both the `redirect_to` and the `respond_to` do a render.

You could try this:

```
def user_formulated_request_properly?
  unless request.post?
    flash[:error] = "This page can only be accessed through the search page. (POST request only)"
    return false
  end

  if params[:query].blank?
    flash[:error] = "Search criteria can not be blank"
    return false
  end

  if !(params[:query] =~ /-/)
    flash[:error] = "( Format of search criteria is wrong.<br /> Should be [IXLSpecClass value][year]-[Message ID] for example GP07-8)"
    return false
  end

  if !(QueryParser.expression.match(params[:query]))
    flash[:error] = %( Format of search criteria is wrong.<br />Should be [IXLSpecClass value][year]-[Message ID] for example GP07-8)
    return false
  end

  return true
end


def show
  if user_formulated_request_properly?
    @statuses = IXLStatus.find(:all)
    @input_messages = InputMessage.search_by(params[:query].strip) unless params[:query].blank?
    @query = params[:query]
  else
    redirect_to(:action => "index") and return
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html #default rendering
  end
end
```

Comment: Does it matter which action is first? Because leaving my original order and your changes, i get `undefined method 'if_user_formulated_request_properly'`

Comment: I changed the name of the method to make it clearer, it's now `user_formulated_request_properly?`.

Comment: Should've been able to correct tht myself :) Anyways worked perfect.. thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

This my solution for some case:

"The underlying reason is that some part of the response_body is assigned before the error is triggered.

You could try clearing the response body before calling render in the exception handler."

```
def render_400
  # Clear the previous response body to avoid a DoubleRenderError
  # when redirecting or rendering another view
  self.response_body = nil

  render(nothing: true, status: 400)
end
```

Source:
[DoubleRenderError in Rails 4.1 when rescuing from InvalidCrossOriginRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351826/doublerendererror-in-rails-4-1-when-rescuing-from-invalidcrossoriginrequest/23351928#23351928)