# DoubleRenderError in Rails 4.1 when rescuing from InvalidCrossOriginRequest

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've upgraded to Rails 4.1.0 today. Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) protection now covers GET requests with JavaScript responses, too.

I have a few remote GET links in the app that are hit by the bots and are now throwing ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest exception.

So I added another rescue_from line to application_controller:

```
rescue_from ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest, with: :render_400
```

Here's the render_400 method:

```
def render_400
    render(nothing: true, status: 400) and return
end
```

I'm still getting **AbstractController::DoubleRenderError** even though I added `and return` as you can see above.

It happens only with the ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest exception. Others like e.g. ActionController::BadRequest and not resulting in AbstractController::DoubleRenderError.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underlying reason is that some part of the `response_body` is assigned before the error is triggered.

You could try clearing the response body before calling `render` in the exception handler.

```
def render_400
  # Clear the previous response body to avoid a DoubleRenderError
  # when redirecting or rendering another view
  self.response_body = nil

  render(nothing: true, status: 400)
end
```

Comment: I'm having the problem with Rails 5.1 and this solution doesn't work :/

Comment: Adding `@_response_body = nil` works in Rails 6.